# Cannot get horizontal menu bar

Tags: html, css, menu

I cannot get my menu bar to appear horizontally. I am still working on the whole page itself, but just need to focus on the #nav items not displaying correctly. Right now it is appearing centered and I would like it to be inline in the upper-right.

How can I fix this?

```css
body {
  background-image: url("http://i59.photobucket.com/albums/g304/ecarlson_2010/Mobile%20Uploads/2E3938F1-33FA-4CF1-A13A-F86E536A7CEA.jpg");
  background-size: 30%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 500px;
  top: 0;
  font-family: cursive;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 500px;
  background-color: black;
}
.left {
  background-color: red;
}
a {
  font-size: 15px;
}
#nav {
  background-color: purple;
  width: 15px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
#nav li {
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  float: right;
  display: inline;
  background-color: pink;
}
#nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<body>


  <header>
    <h1>Plant Tissue Culturing </h1>
    <div id="nav">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#"> HOW TO </a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"> WHY </a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"> HOW TO </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </header>
  <h2>Micropropagation</h2>
  <div class="first">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
  </div>
  </div class="second">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
  <div class="third>
                <p> " Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just need to add `display: inline-block;` to your `#nav li`

```
#nav li {
    margin: 10px;
    float: left;
    background-color: pink;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 25px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Smoggs/4f2hevkg/1/)

```css
body {
  background-image: url("http://i59.photobucket.com/albums/g304/ecarlson_2010/Mobile%20Uploads/2E3938F1-33FA-4CF1-A13A-F86E536A7CEA.jpg");
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  font-family: cursive;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
a {
  font-size: 15px;
}
#nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  float: right;
}
#nav li {
  margin: 10px;
  float: left;
  background-color: pink;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
h2 {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<title>Plant Tissue Culturing</title>
<header>
  <h1>Plant Tissue Culturing </h1>

  <div id="nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#"> HOW TO </a>

      </li>
      <li><a href="#"> WHY </a>

      </li>
      <li><a href="#"> WHERE </a>

      </li>
    </ul>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <h2>Micropropagation</h2>

  </div>
  <br />
</header>

<body>
  <div class="first">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
  </div>
  <div class="second">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
  </div>
  <div class="third">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
  </div>
</body>
```